Toggle "Keep Screen On" feature mid-game

Godot 4.0 provides a Project Setting called "Keep Screen On." This prevents the screensaver, or for mobile devices prevents the screen from dimming and eventually locking. But this Project Setting seems to be unchangable once launched.
How can I allow the system screensaver, but only sometimes? I wish to halt it during crucial moments, but allow it at other times (such as when the game is paused.)

An example in the wild: Mario Kart Tour prevents the screensaver and lock screen during a race, even when it receives no input. But only during a race: The moment you cross the finish line, the device will eventually time out, screensave, and lock.

You can use ProjectSettings as such:
ProjectSettings.set_setting('display/window/energy_saving/keep_screen_on',false)


Already tried this, it doesn't work. It just keeps the value it had at launch.

@4444 can you show the complete code segment you've used? Also generally add what code you've already tried in your questions, it helps those trying to solve your problem

That is the complete code segment I used. I confirmed with the breakpoints that it was being reached, and that the Boolean parameter was correct. It does not change the behavior of the screensaver.
